# If $g$ solves the Einstein equation, does $kg$ also solve the Einstein equation?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

Simple question. If $g_{ij}$ is a solution to:

$R_{ij}-\frac{1}{2} g_{ij}R+g_{ij} \Lambda = 0$,

i.e. the vacuum equation, will $kg_{ij}$ where $k$ is constant also solve it? I know that the Ricci tensor is scale invariant, so my initial answer would be "no"?

Comment: No matter what your conventions, the Ricci tensor and $gR$ scale the same way (i.e., if $R_{ij}$ is scale-invariant, then the trace $R = g^{ij}R_{ij}$ scales to $\frac{1}{k}R$, so $g_{ij}R$ is scale-invariant). If $\Lambda$ is a cosmological constant, I guess the physical conclusion is, scaling a vacuum solution gives a vacuum solution _for a different cosmological constant_.

Comment: Cheers man! Thanks.